# A method that returns the object last in focus?

Tags: java, focus, jbutton, jtextfield

so I have a couple `JButtons`, and hundreds of `JTextFields` throughout a program (with `CardLayout`, don't worry). I want these `JButtons` to find the `JTextField` that was last in focus, so when the button is clicked, it sets the text of that field to be whatever that button is.

I have tried `getFocusOwner()` and `getMostRecentFocusOwner()` on `JTextFields` that were `setFocusable(true)`

I'm hoping there's a method already available somewhere for this.

Comment: Just guessing here. But certainly there is some kind of Focus-Event which provides this information on loosing the focus? This could be stored and later used. s. e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusEvent.html

Comment: Minor improvements to highlighting and formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have getOppositeComponent() in FocusEvent.

which returns the other Component involved in this focus change. For a FOCUS_GAINED event, this is the Component that lost focus. For a FOCUS_LOST event, this is the Component that gained focus. If this focus change occurs with a native application, with a Java application in a different VM or context, or with no other Component, then null is returned.
see documentation for more detail.

or

in the focus lost of TextField assign the textfield to some variable and then use that variable in button click event.